# Remote to server

Tags: powershell, winrm

I have searched the hell out of this and this is my last resort..

So I used to use the following to be able to WinRM into servers:

```
$sessionoption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck

$global:s = New-PSSession -Name RSession -ComputerName $Global:DevicePrimaryIP -Credential $Global:Creds -SessionOption $sessionoption
```

However since then things have changed and the server which my scripts run off have been wiped and locked down. I believe previously I ran the following which resolved this error:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force
```

I am no longer able to run the above as I get the following error:

> New-PSSession : [xx.xx.xx.xx] Connecting to remote server xx.xx.xx.xx failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Can anyone help as I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward. Did you follow the advice given there?

Comment: The error message is quite clear about what the problem is and how to fix it, and gives you a place to go for more information (the documentation). Have you done any of the things it instructs you to do?